# From view to action the ID passed is 0 using PaginatedList<Book>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, pagination, model-binding

This is my controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
        ViewData["GenreSortParm"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "genre_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        var userBooks = _userService.PagedUserBooks(user, sortOrder, currentFilter, searchString, page);
        var result = await PaginatedList<Book>.CreateAsync(userBooks, page ?? 1, 5);

        return View(result);
    }
```

The "userBooks" is an IQueryable so that in "CreateAsync" it can be passed and the "result" that I pass into the View is PaginatedList

In my View I am using a `@model PaginatedList<Book>` and here comes the issue in this part of my View

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Genre
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Title
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.CreatedOn
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Book" asp-action="MakeReview" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Add Review</a>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I use `asp-route-id="@item.Id"` which is the Id of the item, which is Book so that I can pass the Id to the action "MakeReview" as you see specified in the `<a asp-controller="Book" asp-action="MakeReview" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Add Review</a>`
But when I go to my action method

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MakeReview(int bookId)
    {
        var user =  await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        var book = await _bookService.GetById(user, bookId);

        //Not fully implemented
        return View();
    }
```

the int bookId passed as a parameter should be the Id of the book I chose to Review, but it is always 0. Does this have something to do with using the PaginatedList as a model where inside the class I don't have a property of Id? This is my class "PaginatedList"

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
When the paramater in the action MakeReview is of type Book and not int and I pass the ID which is int to the Action then the modelbinding works, of course everything is null except the Id.

Comment: Either `asp-route-id="@item.Id"` should be `asp-route-bookId="@item.Id"` or `int bookId` should be `int id`. As it stands, there's no match between `id` and `bookId`.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the last word after "route" should be the name of the parameter in the Action method!

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It's covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-route-value).